# Reading raw binary image data for Internet Explorer 10 and 11: HTML7007, Data freed

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, blob

I'm currently working on a little image viewer which reads images that are in a local cache and not placed on the file system. So I'm requesting the images data by using a XMLHTTPRequest. No problem so far.. After that I'm generating an ArrayBuffer using that function:

```
function stringToArrayBuffer(string) {
   if(!string.length) return;
   var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(string.length);
   var bufferElem = new Uint8Array(buffer);
   for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
     bufferElem[i] = string.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff;
   }
   return buffer;
}
```

Works fine. Even in Internet Explorer 10 and 11.

Here, after the call of the stringToArrayBuffer() call, begins the Internet Explorer nightmare:

```
function convertImage(tmpstring) {
    var arrayBuffer = stringToArrayBuffer(tmpstring);
    var filereader = new FileReader();
    var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    blob = new Blob([arrayBufferView], {'type': 'image\/jpeg'});
    filereader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    return filereader;
}
```

Works fine in Firefox, Chrome/Chromium and Opera, but Internet Explorer generates strange colorful trash images and the debugger says:

```
HTML7007: One or more blob URLs were revoked by closing the blob for which 
they were created. These URLs will no longer resolve as the data backing the 
URL has been freed.
```

Any ideas on that?